# Can I change className of the antd table's specific tr dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a toggler button in each tr of my ant design table that when the user clicks on it, I want to add/remove a specific class to/from its parent tr.

I know there are ways with vanilla js but I'm coding with React library, so I don't want to manipulate DOM directly.

To be more precise, I already tried `rowClassName` and it won't help! (It adds the given class to all of the rows.)

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox link for you above code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. There is nothing to show, I asked is there a way to dynamically change one tr classes in ant or not!

Comment: `rowClassName` property of antd table is one way of changing the row css, you need to add a condition to change the css class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following example, index.css file has CSS which changes the background color of the row depending on the `Switch` value, and removes the default hover effect of antd

index.css

```
.row-light {
  background-color: #b6c5f5;
}

.row-dark {
  background-color: #84eb84;
}

.ant-table-thead>tr.ant-table-row-hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row-hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-thead>tr:hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td, 
.ant-table-tbody>tr:hover:not(.ant-table-expanded-row)>td {
   background: unset; 
}
```

Following is react code, it uses `rowClassName` property of antd table to change the css class of rows.

Demo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table, Switch } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Demo = () => {
const [users, setUsers] = useState([
{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  age: 32,
  toggle: true,
},
{
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: 42,
  toggle: false,
},
{
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
  toggle: false,
},
{
  key: '4',
  name: 'Peter Black',
  age: 72,
  toggle: true,
},
]);

const columns = [
{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name',
},
{
  title: 'Age',
  dataIndex: 'age',
  key: 'age',
},
{
  title: 'Action',
  key: 'toggle',
  render: (text, record) => (
    <Switch
      size="small"
      onChange={(value) => onSwitchChange(record, value)}
      checked={record.toggle}
    />
  ),
},
];

/* Updates the toggle property(true or false) of selected user */
const onSwitchChange = (record, value) => {
 let key = record.key;
 let data = users.map((user) => {
  if (user.key === record.key) 
  return { ...user, toggle: value };
  else return user;
});
setUsers(data);
console.log(users);
};

return (
<Table
  rowClassName={(record, index) =>
    record.toggle === true ? 'row-light' : 'row-dark'
  }
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={users}
/>
);
};
export default Demo
```

[image: Screenshot]